# MYSQL select gets deleted values (JAVA)

Tags: java, mysql, web-services

I have a mysql database on my ubuntu server. When i delete rows with MYSQL workbench on this database and than try to select these rows with my Java program, i still get the deleted rows. (I have committed the command with MYSQL workbench)
In my java program I access the database over a Java Restful webservice which also runs on my server.

my webservice looks like:

```
@Path("/getAll")
@GET
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})

public List<PV> getAllPV() {
    List<PV> ret =null;
    try { 
        ret=Database.getInstance().getAllPV();
    } catch (Exception e) { 
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
    return ret; 
}
```

My Database:

```
public List<PV> getAllPV() throws Exception{ 
   Connection conn = null;
   PreparedStatement ps=null;
   Statement s = null;
   conn = getDBConnection();
   conn.setAutoCommit(false);
   List<PV> ret = new ArrayList<PV>(); 
   s = conn.createStatement();
   ResultSet rs = s.executeQuery("select * from PV"); 
   ... 
   conn.close();
}
```

Has anyone an idea ?

Comment: You will need to provide details about the database access behind your REST web-service, it is possible that the query is fetching and caching values internally...

Comment: Maybe the webservice is using caching?  Eg, most JPA implementations will cache unless instructed otherwise.

Comment: please edit the post instead of adding information as comments

Comment: @fvu how can i turn off catching?

Comment: This doesn't seem to be JPA based code, and I've never seen JDBC code cache like this.

Comment: What is happening in `getDBConnection();`?
Look at this http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html for configuration info